# Bitlocker encryption on data shared over network

Tags: windows-7, networking, encryption, bitlocker

Is there a way to restrict users to access encrypted data shared over the network using Bitlocker on windows 7 ultimate?

Meaning - any user accessing the shared data which is on the windows 7 bitlocker encrypted disk would need to specify the key. Just like the authentication check it does for the key before booting/starting up of the system.

Answer (score 1):

No, but the Windows built in file encryption service requires users to supply their authorized certificate to access the files.